# Wide Method Call VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

I've just written this:

```
ldb.Update(emp.Code,emp.number, "text", String.Empty, "EMP", emp.scheme, emp.status, emp.tod, emp.timestamp, emp.Code, emp.oldfrmd)
```

Its far to wide! How can I shorten this method call?  The problem is this isn't my method, so I can't edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what your concern is:

- Too many parameters? Can't really change that without changing the method, although you could introduce a proxying method containing fewer parameters, where each parameter may map to several of the original ones. It looks like you might want to make this a method on whatever the type of `emp` is, but it's hard to know without more information.
- Just too wide on the screen? Use line continuations:

  ```
  ldb.Update(emp.Code, emp.number, "text", String.Empty, "EMP", _
             emp.scheme, emp.status, emp.tod, emp.timestamp, _
             emp.Code, emp.oldfrmd)
  ```

  (IIRC the "_" isn't actually needed in VB10.)
- Too many characters? Introduce some local variables, potentially, shortening the eventual call to something like:

  ```
  ldb.Update(code, number, "text", "", "EMP", scheme, status, _
             tod, timestamp, code, oldfrmd)
  ```

  (Although your *overall* code will be bigger, of course.)

Comment: Definitely. Looks like a typical CRUD method. Converting to an ORM would help to, but if you can't change the code, that's not much of an option. Can't wait to get onto vb10, BTW, just the auto line continuation is enough for me!

Comment: You could also add the "with" statment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change the method signature, you must really be passing all those fields of emp into it.  I would tend to write my own function (pardon my terribly rusty VB; I'm sure there's something wrong with this):

```
updateLdb(Employee e)
```

which simply called ldb's function and did nothing more.  Using a single letter for a variable name is generally a bad idea, but in this case it saves your line 16 characters, and in a one-line function, "e" isn't particularly less informative than "emp".  As Jon says if you move this function into the Employee class, you can get rid of another 16 characters - and it does appear to really belong there.

I would not use "e" as a variable or parameter name in any function that is longer than one or two lines, but in that small a scope, I think you can get away with it without significantly sacrificing readability.